# Chart multipile fields in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, logstash, analytics, kibana

I am trying to create a pie chart in Kibana (V2.3.1) which displays values from multiple fields.

Lets say I got documents representing humans with the following fields: (representing if the finger is bent or straight)
Human 1:

- human.right_arm.thumb = bent
- human.right_arm.pinky = straight
- human.left_arm.thumb = straight
- human.left_arm.pinky = half-bent

Human 2:

- human.right_arm.thumb = straight
- human.right_arm.pinky = bent
- human.left_arm.thumb = half-bent
- human.left_arm.pinky = half-bent

Now I want to create a pie chart on the status of all the fingers. It would create a result like:

- bent (= 2) = 25% coverage of the pie
- straight (= 3) = 37.5% coverage of the pie
- half-bent (= 3) = 37.5% coverage of the pie

In Kibana I can only split one field per chart. So **how do I combine the results for all fingers?**

And **how can I get the same status but then from all the thumbs?**

---

I think scripted fields are the way to go, but I cannot figure out how since as far as I can see the aggregation only combines the results of fields while it should represent a set of fields ("all fingers" or "all thumbs").

I searched the web and found similar issues but never a clear answer.

If necessary I can make changes in Logstash. We use the ruby/code filter to define these fields.

---

Note: Sadly I am not able to update our ELK stack to a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make the state of the finger an separate aggregatable field? Then you'll be able to create a pie chart with a count metric and split the slices by terms and then choose the field with the name of the state of the finger.

Eg.

[image]

Otherwise, this scripted field might work (not tested since I don't have the necessary setup):

```
def fingerState = doc['whatever the field is called'].value; 
if (fingerState != null) 
{ 
    int index = fingerState.lastIndexOf('='); 
    if (index > 0) 
    { 
        return fingerState.substring(index+1); 
    } 
} 
return fingerState; //this will return the whole thing if for some reason this format isnt consistent
```

As for the second question, you can do something like

[image]

but for this to work you need to make the state of finger aggregatable.

Hope this works and that it's compatible with your version on ELK (I'm using 5.2)